# Can I use Oracle Pipelined Function like a select in QueryDSL?

Tags: oracle, querydsl, pipelined-function

For a specific reason of a requirement, instead of using a VIEW, I use an Oracle pipelined function to get data in a table.

It works perfectly using Native Query:

```
"select * from (table (PAC_FOO_PIPELINED.FUNCTION_BAR(:fooDate, :barDate)))"
```

The problem is that I need to use QueryDSL. If I use native query, it would be necessary to rewrite a lot of code that is now bound to abstract methods  that were implemented using QueryDSL.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to perform this select through QueryDSL?

Comment: What happens when you try to use QueryDSL with that query? You have one more level of parentheses than are needed, is it happier with those removed? i.e. `select * from table(foo(:x,:y))` without the whole `table()` call enclosed. If not, are you able to create a view of that query - or can't you create views at all for some reason?

Comment: Yeah, I can't create a view in this situation because of the where. The dates used in where need to be passed as params. So I used a function to do that.

I have no idea how to write this query in QueryDSL.